# Como implementar Fileupload num projeto Hibernate com JSF?

Tags: hibernate, jsf, primefaces, java-ee, file-upload

Estou com um projeto JSF com o modelo DAO usando Hibernate, e estou tendo muita dificuldade para entender como salvar a imagem no banco de dados.

Eu somente precisaria saber como ficaria o método para salvar uma imagem em uma classe DAO e como ele ficaria na classe Bean.

Encontrei esse vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2b3KQApdOAU

Esse chegou mais próximo do que precisava: http://www.guj.com.br/39230-jsf2---upload-de-imagens

Esse foi um repositório que encontrei: https://github.com/wladyband/fileupload

Esse é o projeto pelo qual estou trabalhando: https://github.com/wladyband/Drogaria/tree/master/Drogaria

E essa é a classe que quero introduzir a modificação: https://github.com/wladyband/Drogaria/blob/master/Drogaria/src/br/com/drogaria/domain/Produto.java

```
package br.com.drogaria.domain;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMax;
import javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMin;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_produtos")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Produto.listar", query = "SELECT p from Produto p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Produto.buscarPorCodigo", query = "SELECT p from Produto p where p.codigo = :codigo") })

public class Produto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "pro_codigo")
    private Long codigo;

    @NotEmpty(message="O campo descrição é obrigatório")
    @Size(min=5,max=50, message="Tamanho invalido para o campo (5 - 50)")
    @Column(name = "pro_descricao", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String descricao;

    @NotNull(message="O campo é obrigatório")
    @DecimalMin(value="0.0", message="Informe um valor ou igual a zero para o campo preço")
    @DecimalMax(value="99999.99", message="Informe um valor menor que 100 mil para o campo preço")
    @Column(name = "pro_preco", precision = 7, scale = 2, nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal preco;

    @NotNull(message="O campo é obrigatório")
    @Min(value = 0, message="Informe um valor maior ou igual a zero para o campo quantidade")
    @Max(value = 9999, message="Informe um valor menor ou igual a 9999 para o campo quantidade")
    @Column(name = "pro_quantidade", nullable = false)
    private Integer quantidade;

    @NotNull(message="O campo fabricante é obrigatório")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tbl_fabrincantes_fab_codigo", referencedColumnName = "fab_codigo", nullable = false)
    private Fabricante fabricante;

    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPreco() {
        return preco;
    }

    public void setPreco(BigDecimal preco) {
        this.preco = preco;
    }

    public Integer getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    public void setQuantidade(Integer quantidade) {
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }

    public Fabricante getFabricante() {
        return fabricante;
    }

    public void setFabricante(Fabricante fabricante) {
        this.fabricante = fabricante;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Produto [codigo=" + codigo + ", descricao=" + descricao
                + ", preco=" + preco + ", quantidade=" + quantidade
                + ", fabricante=" + fabricante + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Produto other = (Produto) obj;
        if (codigo == null) {
            if (other.codigo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

O site do GUJ me ajudou um pouco com essa postagem, sendo que ainda não consegui resolver meu problema.

http://www.guj.com.br/39728-como-gravar-imagens-na-base-de-dados-em-jsf

Eu sei que a maneira de fazer é parecido com esse modelo abaixo, eu somente precisaria saber como adaptar esse modelo ao meu projeto.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "fileUploadMB")
@RequestScoped
public class fileUploadMB {
    public static byte[] arquivo;
    public static String nomeArquivo;
    private Ouvidoria ouvidoriaCadastro;

    public Ouvidoria getOuvidoriaCadastro() {
        if (ouvidoriaCadastro == null) {
            ouvidoriaCadastro = new Ouvidoria();
        }
        return ouvidoriaCadastro;
    }


    public void setOuvidoriaCadastro(Ouvidoria ouvidoriaCadastro) {
        this.ouvidoriaCadastro = ouvidoriaCadastro;
    }

    /* Método que faz o Upload dos arquivos */
    public void doUpload(FileUploadEvent fileUploadEvent) throws IOException {

        UploadedFile uploadedFile = fileUploadEvent.getFile();

        String fileNameUploaded = uploadedFile.getFileName();
        long fileSizeUploaded = uploadedFile.getSize();
        System.out.println(uploadedFile);

        // arquivo = uploadedFile.getContents();
        String infoAboutFile = "<br/> Arquivo recebido: <b>" + fileNameUploaded
                + "</b><br/>" + "Tamanho do Arquivo: <b>" + fileSizeUploaded
                + "</b>";
        //Mensagem exibida na tela
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        facesContext.addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage("Sucesso", infoAboutFile));

        arquivo = (IOUtils.toByteArray(uploadedFile.getInputstream()));
        nomeArquivo = uploadedFile.getFileName();

        ouvidoriaCadastro.setArquivo(arquivo);
        ouvidoriaCadastro.setNomeArquivo(fileNameUploaded);
        ouvidoriaCadastro.setNomeArquivo(nomeArquivo);

        System.out.println("Arquivo capturado" + arquivo);
        System.out.println("Nome do Arquivo" + nomeArquivo);

    }

}
```

Página:

```html
<p:outputLabel value="Selecione um Arquivo(Opcional):" />
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadMB.doUpload}"
    mode="advanced" showButtons="false" label="Enviar Arquvios.." auto="true" />
```

Comment: O que seria necessário para evitar a duplicata?

Comment: Você pode editar sua pergunta incluindo o detalhes desta pergunta, uma vez que é a mesmo. Para editar a outra questão, acesse este link: [Editar Como gravar imagem no banco de dados com JSF2](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/62855/edit). Depois disto, considere remover esta pergunta.

Comment: Desculpa, eu não entendi.